# serialized json size is much more than pickled or original dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pickle

i want to send a python dictionary through the network sockets.
i used `ujson` and `json` for dumping dictionary but the result size is too much than original dictionary.

original dictionary size is around `1mb`
json size is around `6mb`
and pickled result is around `1mb`

i used `asizeof` from `pympler` and builtin `len` function for getting size of results.

note that dictionary contains some binary data that encoded to `base64` for converting to text data.

Comment: This is because json needs to turn your dict into a string. Encoding the fat that your data structure is a dict requires some space, but the real space-consumer is your binary data, which needs to be stringified. `pickle` saves as binary data, which is why you're able to get away with using only as much space as the dict uses in the first place

Comment: @inspectorG4dget binary data is encoded as `base64` before dumping to json or pickle.

Comment: But json stores this base64 data as a string, which I'm pretty sure is bigger than raw bytes, which is how pickle stores it (and probably therefore takes advantage of some sort of compression)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget i gzipped json data via `zlib` but it's around `3mb`. because `base64` result is text based i thinks `json` and `pickle` processing it in the same way. am i wrong?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: base64 encode increases the size by about 50%, not enough to explain what you see.

Comment: @Cuadue OP is clearly asking about the unexpected size of the json string.

Comment: Are you encoding to utf-8 or utf-16? (8 is default for json.dump). Any chance your string data is expanding to multibyte utf8 (that is, is mostly outside of the ascii range)?

Comment: @tdelaney all strings in my application are unicode (utf-8) strings.

Comment: utf-8 can expand a character to up to 4 bytes. I was playing with some Chinese text that was about 3 bytes per character. Dicts that contain large inteters could expand quite a bit also. I still don't make it to 6x increase, though.

Comment: @tdelaney i guess the main problem is with `base64` and utf-8 characters as you said but another reason is the dicts that is referenced in other dicts that cause duplicate result in json. now result size is around `3.5mb` that is more acceptable than `6mb` but yet seems too much. thank you